# Java - Format double array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, printf

I have created a loop below that will display around 50 numbers 'at random' between 1 & 999. 
The problem I have is that I need to print out the entire array outside the loop (as attempted) but I need it in the same format I have printed it within the loop.

I have tried a few ways of doing it, but it keeps throwing errors, mainly to do with 'illegal conversions'.

```
// Imports
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

// Class
public class Random50
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Declaration
    double[] Random50Array = new double[51];
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("000");
    int i;

    // Loops
    for(i = 0; i < Random50Array.length; i++)
    {
      Random50Array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 999);
      System.out.print(df.format(Random50Array[i]) + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    String RandomArray = (Arrays.toString(Random50Array));
    System.out.printf("%03d", RandomArray);
  }
 }
```

I appreciate any future guidance given. :)

Comment: you've managed to violate almost all of the Java conventions for code formatting, and your Java looks like C!  -- no but in seriousness, which lines are throwing the exception, and you should post the stack trace as well.

Comment: `RandomArray` is a String object, while %d signifies a decimal integer. That's why you are getting Illegal format exception.

Comment: @AliAmiri: clearly, OP wants to take up three digits for all numbers (e.g. 24 --> "024"), which can't be done with System.out.print.

Answer (score 2):

You could append the formatted strings within the loop together, and print them out all at once at the end.

```
// ...
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(i = 0; i < Random50Array.length; i++)
{
  Random50Array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*999);
  String output = df.format(Random50Array[i])+ ", ";
  System.out.print(output);
  builder.append(output);
}

System.out.println("");
System.out.println("");
System.out.print(builder.toString());
```

Note that you shouldn't use `System.out.printf("%03d", "...");` to print strings, since the `"%03d"` means that the argument you are passing is a number. This is the cause of the errors you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Optimized Code: You do not need double array, don't you

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(i = 0; i < Random50Array.length; i++)
{
  String output = df.format((int)(Math.random()*999)+ ", ";
  builder.append(output);
}

System.out.println("");
System.out.println("");
System.out.print(builder.toString());
```